# Linking Buttons Together

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create some kind of linkage between some buttons on the form so that when i click a button it highlights all the previous buttons to it [some kind of volume controller]

[image]

Imagine it as a volume controller. All these colored buttons will be gray and what i want to achieve is as you click on a button it colorizes all the buttons before it; However IDK what is the best way to make a behavior like this without involving tons of useless codes...

Comment: WinForms or WPF? I've added [WinForms] to your question based on your accepted answer.

Comment: Hmm, well I tried to add [WinForms] to your question but now it says my edit is pending "peer review" ...

Comment: If you want to get really fancy you could actually create the Button controls at runtime. That would avoid the ugly set of 20 assignment statements, but perhaps not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to add all the buttons to an array then handle it from there

#### Code

```
//Create an array of buttons and hook up the Click event of each of them
private Button[] VolumeButtons { get; set; }

public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Assuming that you have 21 buttons as it appears in your picture...
    VolumeButtons = new Button[21];
    VolumeButtons[0] = button1;
    VolumeButtons[1] = button2;
    VolumeButtons[2] = button3;
    VolumeButtons[3] = button4;
    VolumeButtons[4] = button5;
    VolumeButtons[5] = button6;
    VolumeButtons[6] = button7;
    VolumeButtons[7] = button8;
    VolumeButtons[8] = button9;
    VolumeButtons[9] = button10;
    VolumeButtons[10] = button11;
    VolumeButtons[11] = button12;
    VolumeButtons[12] = button13;
    VolumeButtons[13] = button14;
    VolumeButtons[14] = button15;
    VolumeButtons[15] = button16;
    VolumeButtons[16] = button17;
    VolumeButtons[17] = button18;
    VolumeButtons[18] = button19;
    VolumeButtons[19] = button20;
    VolumeButtons[20] = button21;

    foreach (var volumeButton in VolumeButtons)
        volumeButton.Click += VolumeButton_Click;
}

void VolumeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Find the index of the clicked button
    int index = Array.FindIndex(VolumeButtons, 0, VolumeButtons.Length, button => button == ((Button)sender));

    //Set the color of all the previous buttons to Aqua, and all the forward buttons to gray [ you may play with it to match your colors then ]
    for (int i = 0; i < VolumeButtons.Length; i++)
        VolumeButtons[i].BackColor = i <= index ? Color.Aqua : Color.Gray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the buttons in an array
2. Create a click event that looks up the index `n` of the button (`sender`) in the array and sets the style of each button `0` - `n` appropriately.
3. Wire up each button to the click event

Do as much as you can on your own and come back with specific questions as necessary.

Comment: how to look up the index of the clicked button ?